# Not selected Advanced options

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-generation

[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dewp7.png)
[image]

> Error:
>   Advanced SQL Generation options not selected

how to select this option
Please check the screenshot

Comment: tag proper keyword .its sql server not mysql

Comment: I fixed the tags. @shailesh, in the future, choose more accurate tags, and you will attract the attention of people best able to answer your questions.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin       Ok sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you needed to do was add a `primary key` to the table.

And the `primary key` must be select as part of the fields you `query`, even if you hide it later.